# Showing entries within a category

Tags: categories, relations

I have a list of people with skills defined by a category group.

I have a category field within the '**people**' Section so when a new person (entry) is created, the category field allows the admin to assign appropriate **skills** to that new profile.

I have a series of category entries for the 'skills' available.

When a user visits an "Our Skills" entry page, I need to display the title (name) of the people who have had that particular skill assigned to their profile via the category field.

I think this is reverse relations but I can't get my head around it?

Would appreciate some help.

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, one could call this a reverse-relation. The field you created the relation from is the "people" entry and you're looking at it from the category element's page.

To describe this direction in Craft [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter, you define whether the element you're dealing with is the [`sourceElement`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) of that relation, which means it is the element with the field, or if it is a [`targetElement`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param), one of the elements selected in the field.

So on your "Our Skills" page you have a category element that *got* selected from a categories field, this makes it a `targetElement`. I'm also setting that categories field's handle here.

```
{% set individuals = craft.entries({
    section: 'people',
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: category,
        field: 'mySkillsFieldHandle'
    }
}) %}
```

In most cases you could just use the `element` property, because there are no other relations between both elements. But I actually like to always define my relations precisely, because who knows what we add to the site in the future, that potentially breaks loose definitions.